# How to search Table with all columns by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am working with tables, I want to perform search by match in all columns. Following code only matches first column data of the table. But I want it should search by all column data. If you have any idea how I can do this, please share with me. Thanks in Advance!

**JsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/hbrjy04m/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="https://teluguhitflopmovieslist.blogspot.com/">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</a></td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td><a href="https://lyricxona.blogspot.com/">UK</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td><a href="https://castxona.blogspot.com/">France</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also, take a look at my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62621136/9765167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to loop through all the `td`s in a `tr` and search the combined text.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    const tableData = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    let allTextContent = '';
    for (let ind = 0; ind < tableData.length; ind++) {
        allTextContent += tableData[ind].innerText;
    }
    
    if (allTextContent) {
      if (allTextContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Although you can avoid the additional loop and search the entire `textContent` of a row instead. A few things can be refactored too.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgxfjmz4/).

```
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');
const tableRows = document.querySelector('#myTable').querySelectorAll('tr');

searchInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const searchInputValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  tableRows.forEach(row => {
    const doesRowMatch = row.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchInputValue);
    if (doesRowMatch) {
      row.style.display = 'table-row';
    } else {
      row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const search = document.querySelector("input[name=search]");
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
const rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");

search.addEventListener("input", () => {
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const matches = row.textContent
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(search.value.toLowerCase())

    matches ? row.classList.remove("hide") : row.classList.add("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

input[name=search] {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://teluguhitflopmovieslist.blogspot.com/">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</a></td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td><a href="https://lyricxona.blogspot.com/">UK</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work even if you increase the number of columns

Basically, you traverse all `TD` inside `TR` and if you find one match, you go to the next row.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")
    var foundInRow = false
    for(j=0; j<tds.length; j++){
    if(foundInRow)
        continue
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        foundInRow = true
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
   if (td) {
     txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
     if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
       tr[i].style.display = "";
       i++;
     } else {
       tr[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }  
   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
   if (td) {
     txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
     if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
       tr[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
       tr[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }       
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjb1rx6f/1/

This works, but the other answers are better...

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code seems to be because of this `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`.
Instead iterate the `tr` and get the text content from each of the `td`. Check if the user input is included in the string. Then show the `tr` else hide `it`

```js
function myFunction() {
  // get user input
  const userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.trim().toUpperCase();
  
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((item) => {
    const tdTxt = [...item.querySelectorAll('td')].map(elem => elem.textContent.trim().toUpperCase()).join(',');

    if (tdTxt.indexOf(userInput) === -1) {
      item.style.display = "none"
    } else {
      item.style.display = "";
    }

  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://teluguhitflopmovieslist.blogspot.com/">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</a></td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td><a href="https://lyricxona.blogspot.com/">UK</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td><a href="https://castxona.blogspot.com/">France</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```